# How to escape json in dynamic content in ADF V2 in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm calling Azure function and I'm building the request body using dynamic content.

This is how I build it:

```
{
  "test": "Test1",
  "data": "@{activity('Upload SKU').output}"
}
```

I have problem with the "data" node. `@{activity('Upload SKU').output` is a json string.
So the dynamic content creates "mess". It doesn't escape it.

It creates this:

```
{
  "test": "Test1",
  "data": "{"a": "1"}"
}
```

**How to escape `@{activity('Upload SKU').output` so that `{"a": "1"}` creates `{\"a\": \"1\"}` so that it can be treated as a string and not as a node under `"data"`.**

This is what I want to achieve:

```
{
  "test": "Test1",
  "data": "{\"a\": \"1\"}"
}
```

Comment: Hi,any progress here with your issue?

Comment: @JayGong there is bug in ADF Expression editor. When I put exactly the same expression directly into "body" field without using expression editor it works. So it turns out there is error in ADF expression editor.

Comment: ok,i tried to summarize your statement in the answer,if you don't mind, would you please accept it to end this case?thx.

Answer (score 1):

You could get some clues from my previous case:[Error "BadRequest" when calling Azure Function in ADF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917900/error-badrequest-when-calling-azure-function-in-adf/58949987#58949987).

The solution is using `@json()` and `@concat()` in dynamic content.For you, the entire `data` may looks like:

```
@json(concat('{"test": "Test1,"data":"',@{activity('Upload SKU').output,'"}'))
```

---

Just for summary:

It turns out there is error in ADF expression editor because when @Hooch put exactly the same expression directly into "body" field without using expression editor it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I've solved it using the JSON escape method discussed at [How should I escape strings in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json).

In your case my ADF expression would looks like

```
{
  "test": "Test1",
  "data": "@{replace(replace(activity('Upload SKU').output, '\', '\\'), '"','\"')}"
}
```